# Can any one explain briefly about the link analysis in nutch

Tags: nutch

Can any one explain briefly about the link analysis in nutch and give some use full links regarding link analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The Nutch Link analysis details can be found here
https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NewScoring